# Selenium C# class name appears multiple times

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i use  selenuim and i try without success to find the element  class="user-card_photo" each time for click in new browser , but i can not do this. Can anyone help me to find with selenuim one way driver find the class class="user-card_photo"

```
  <body>
          <div id="search">
                <div class="justify search">
                    <div class="search_col">
                        <div class="user-card">
                            <div class="user-card_photo">

                            </div>
                            <div class="user-card_photo_section">

                            </div>
                        </div>                   
                        <div class="user-card">
                            <div class="user-card_photo">

                            </div>
                            <div class="user-card_photo_section">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="search_col">
                        <div class="user-card">
                            <div class="user-card_photo">

                            </div>
                            <div class="user-card_photo_section">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="user-card">
                            <div class="user-card_photo">

                            </div>
                            <div class="user-card_photo_section">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="user-card">
                            <div class="user-card_photo">

                            </div>
                            <div class="user-card_photo_section">

                            </div>
                        </div>                 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
```

i would appreciate if someone put c# code to answer my question

Comment: Could you edit your post to make it clearer what you are trying to do? What do you mean by: "take the element class="user-card_photo" each time for click in new browser"??

Comment: sorry for my poor english i hope it be better now

Answer (score 0):

You have several div-elements with the class "user-card_photo". It's not completely clear what you want from your question, but I guess you might need the following:

To get all divs with the class "user-card_photo" do this:

```
List<WebElement> photos = driver.findElements(By.className("user-card_photo"));
```

Now you can loop through all div-elements that have the class "user-card_photo":

```
for(WebElement photo : photos) {
    // do whatever you like with the single elements now
}
```

Or if you're interested in only one of the div-elements you can get them by index

```
WebElement photo01 = photos.get(0);
WebElement photo02 = photos.get(1);
...
```

*It's Java Code, but it's pretty simple and a good practice for you to bring this into C# code ;-)*